# Organizing classes and properties in PHP - the right way?

Tags: php, oop, architecture, static

Please help me. I need a better understanding PHP OOP principles.

If I have a class property which is immutable for all of the class instances it should be defined as static? 
If so, is there a way to be sure that static properties are defined in all classes of that type? As I read in PHP manual, static properties cannot be controller neither by the interface nor by abstract classes? Or am I wrong?

Simple example.

```
<?php

// Parent class
abstract class Employee 
{
    abstract public function getAlias();
}

// Child classes
class Manager extends Employee 
{

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'manager';
    }
}
class Security extends Employee 
{
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'security';
    }   
}
```

Tell me, where an `alias` property should be placed? 
I have to be sure that any Employee descendants that will be created in future will have that property defined. Is it OK to keep that kind of properties in dynamic methods? Or they should be placed in constants, static methods or static properties?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit, what you intend to use the alias for?

Comment: For example, `alias` property (as far as any similar one) can be stored in DB table and used for Single Table Inheritance - instantiate a proper class based on retrieved DB records' alias.

Comment: you could just use the actual class name instead of an alias in that case. `Manager::class` would give you the fully qualified class name. Also, shouldn't your ORM handle that for you? Don't get me wrong. It's a valid question. It just smells like something that could or should be handled through type checking instead. But to decide that needs some context.

Comment: TBH, your `Employee` instance should either contain only the business logic or only contain the SQL code. And a table name is something that should actually be governed via configuration instead of hardcoding it in the class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the current version is quite ok (if considered with no context) because it makes for a cleaner code, since it closer matches [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Technically, you could rewrite it as this (but that would actually **make it worse** code):

```
abstract class Employee {
    public function getAlias() {
        return $this->alias;
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    protected $alias = 'mngr';
}


$user = new Manager;
echo $user->getAlias();
```

<kbd>Live code: https://3v4l.org/sjVOT</kbd>

The more important aspect is the purpose of this code. You mentioned, that you would want to use something like this for dealing with single-table inheritance, but here is the important part:

*Your domain entities should not be aware of how your persistence layer works*.

And pulling structural information from the domain layer for use in some query-builder is a terrible idea. I would recommend for you to instead looks at [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern (you probably should actually read the [PoEAA](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420) book).

Your domain entities should not know any details about how (or even "if") they is being saved or restored.